# Why this regex splits the last character from a string in another group?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex to capture a string, but I don't know why the output puts the last character before the separator in another group

This is the regex I'm using:

```
(\w|\d|\s)*
```

This is the string I'm using for test:

```
Eleccion Nacional 2017
```

So in one group I get: `Eleccion Nacional 2017`

And in another I get: `7`

Could anyone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: You are alternating for a `word (\w)` or a `digit (\d)` or a `whitespace (\s)`

Comment: You are repeating the capturing group giving the value of the last iteration in the capturing group. You could also use `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*` to prevent matching leading and trailing spaces as \w also matches \d

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Here we might want to simply add a list of chars with a capturing group:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)
```

Of-course, we can add more boundaries to it, if necessary, such as:

```
([A-Za-z\s]+[0-9]{4})
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fegNkN/1)

Or we can try your original expression:

```
([\w\d\s]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwwQz8/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

We can check in the visualizer how your original expression works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first result is the whole match: the pattern `(\w|\d|\s)*` matches all of the input `Eleccion Nacional 2017`. This first result isn't the result of a capture group. It is the whole character sequence matched by the entire pattern.

The second result is the value of the capture group, which contains only the final match of the parenthesized group which has the `*` applied.